# Anti join followed by union in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, union, anti-join

I am running PySpark script in which I am doing anti join & union of 2 dataframes. But I want to do it in Spark SQL.

df_src:

```
+-------+-------+
|call_id|call_nm|
+-------+-------+
|    100|     QC|
|    105|     XY|
|    110|     NM|
|    115|     AB|
+-------+-------+
```

df_lkp:

```
+-------+-------+
|call_id|call_nm|
+-------+-------+
|    100|     QC|
|    105|     XY|
|    106|     XZ|
+-------+-------+
```

We have two dataframes: df_src & df_lkp. I am extracting unmatched records from df_src:

```
df_unmatched = df_src.join(df_lkp, on=column_nm, how='left_anti')
```

It is giving this result:

df_unmatched

```
+-------+-------+
|call_id|call_nm|
+-------+-------+
|    110|     NM|
|    115|     AB|
+-------+-------+
```

But I want to do this part using Spark SQL. I have created temporary view `vw_df_src` & `vw_df_lkp` and trying to run the following query, but not getting the result.

```
unmatched_sql = "SELECT * from vw_df_src where {0} in (select {0} from vw_df_src minus select {0} from vw_df_lkp)".format('call_id')
df_unmatched = sqlContext.sql(unmatched_sql)
```

I am also doing union of both the dataframes and dropping duplicates. I am using below code:

```
df_src1 = df_lkp.union(df_src)
df_src1.show(10)
df_src2 = df_src1.dropDuplicates(['call_id'])
```

df_src2:

```
+-------+-------+
|call_id|call_nm|
+-------+-------+
|    110|     NM|
|    100|     QC|
|    115|     AB|
|    106|     XZ|
|    105|     XY|
+-------+-------+
```

I want this to be done in Spark SQL too.

I am using the following code to create temp views:

```
df_src = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter", '\001').options(header='true',inferSchema='false').load(src_file_nm)
df_src.createOrReplaceTempView('vw_df_src')
df_lkp = sqlContext.read.format('com.databricks.spark.csv').option("delimiter", '\001').options(header='true',inferSchema='false').load(lkp_file)
df_lkp.createOrReplaceTempView('vw_df_lkp')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ANTI JOIN**

```
spark.sql(
"""select * from vw_df_src LEFT ANTI JOIN 

vw_df_lkp  ON

vw_df_src.call_nm= vw_df_lkp.call_nm """).show()


+-------+-------+
|call_id|call_nm|
+-------+-------+
|    115|     AB|
|    110|     NM|
+-------+-------+
```

If running in a notebook cell not initialed as sql TRY

```
%sql 
select * from vw_df_src LEFT ANTI JOIN 

vw_df_lkp  ON

vw_df_src.call_nm= vw_df_lkp.call_nm
```

**UNION**

In `pyspark`, union returns duplicates and you have to `drop_duplicates`() or use `distinct()`. In sql, union eliminates duplicates. The following will therefore do. `Spark 2.0.0 unionall()` retuned duplicates and `union` is the thing

```
spark.sql(
"""select * from vw_df_src

union

select * from vw_df_lkp""" ).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Preset:

```py
df_src = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(100, 'QC'),
     (105, 'XY'),
     (110, 'NM'),
     (115, 'AB')],
    ['call_id', 'call_nm']
)
df_lkp = spark.createDataFrame(
    [(100, 'QC'),
     (105, 'XY'),
     (105, 'XY'),
     (106, 'XZ')],
    ['call_id', 'call_nm']
)
df_src.createOrReplaceTempView('vw_df_src')
df_lkp.createOrReplaceTempView('vw_df_lkp')
```

According to your requirements, (anti join + union) can be done like this:

```py
spark.sql(
    """
    select *
    from vw_df_src as a
    anti join vw_df_lkp b on a.call_nm=b.call_nm
    union (select * from vw_df_lkp)
    """
).show()
# +-------+-------+
# |call_id|call_nm|
# +-------+-------+
# |    110|     NM|
# |    115|     AB|
# |    100|     QC|
# |    105|     XY|
# |    106|     XZ|
# +-------+-------+
```

However, it seems that anti join is not needed:

```py
spark.sql(
    """
    select * from vw_df_src
    union
    select * from vw_df_lkp
    """
).show()
# +-------+-------+
# |call_id|call_nm|
# +-------+-------+
# |    100|     QC|
# |    105|     XY|
# |    115|     AB|
# |    110|     NM|
# |    106|     XZ|
# +-------+-------+
```